# Watch OS 2.0 Actionable remote push notification is not working on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I am developing a project in watch 2.0 using wcsession.
My actionable notification has two type of button that is accept and reject.When i click on accept or reject ActionWithIdentifier then my delegate method is not call.

I am using this delegate in extensiondeleget.m

```
1.- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier     forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification
{
     dicPlayLoad=remoteNotification;
       self.strActionNotificationType = identifier;
    [self notification:identifier withDic:remoteNotification];

}

2.- (void)handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo
{
dicPlayLoad=remoteNotification;
self.strActionNotificationType = identifier;
[self notification:identifier withDic:responseInfo];
}


-(void)notification:(NSString *)strIdentifier withDic:(NSDictionary *)dic
{
self.strActionNotificationType = @"";

if ([strIdentifier isEqualToString:ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER])
{
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [dic objectForKey:@"aps"];
    self.strStrRequestId = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"REQUEST_ID"];
    self.strActionNotificationType = ACCEPT_PAYMENT_IDENTIFIER;
  [self showAlertWithStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert message:EXTENSION_DELGATE.strStrRequestId title:@"Alert"];
}
else if ([strIdentifier isEqualToString:REJECT_IDENTIFIER])
{
    // do action for reject payment
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [dic objectForKey:@"aps"];
    self.strActionNotificationType =isEqualToString:REJECT_IDENTIFIER;
    // do action for accept payment
  [self showAlertWithStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert message:EXTENSION_DELGATE.strStrRequestId title:@"Alert"];
}

}
```

but when i show my strIdentifier  in alert view it show empty string.